# Git lists tracked files as untracked on rebase. How do I perform a rebase like this?

Tags: git

When I try `git rebase branch1 branch2`, or after `git checkout branch2`, `git pull origin branch1 --rebase`, I get the following message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
<list of files here>
Aborting
fatal: Could not detach HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

However, when I run git status, nothing shows up. If I try to checkout a different branch, it works. If I remove the files, they show up as deleted in the git status, so the rebase still fails. When I stash the changes, the situation is the same as described initially.

I have tried running `git clean -fd`. Renaming the index file so a new one is created. I checked that the files are not ignored in the `.gitignore file`.

What could the problem be here?

Comment: What exactly is the output of `git status` at the beginning?

Comment: The tracked-ness of a file is determined by whether the file is in the index (aka staging area). Git's index gets *changed* (re-set) by various operations, so files that *were* tracked a moment ago can be *untracked* now, and files that are untracked now can become tracked. This can get pretty messy, especially if you fiddle with the index flags (`--assume-unchanged` and `--skip-worktree`).